# Errors in faces-config after upgrade to JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2.2, myfaces, faces-config

After upgrading the JSF implementation in our project from Myfaces 1.1 to MyFaces 2.2.12, my IDE (IntelliJ) shows me errors for all `navigation-rule` and `managed-bean` entries in my `faces-config.xml`. I have changed the root element in that file from

```
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.0//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_0.dtd">

<faces-config>
```

to

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
```

`navigation-rule` entries like the following used to work and didn't show any errors before the upgrade:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>exampleOutcome</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/newpages/view1.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

After the upgrade to JSF 2.2, the `navigation-case` element is error-marked with a red underline. When hovering the text with the mouse, I get the error message:

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'navigation-case'. One of '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":from-view-id}' is expected.
```

Does this mean the `from-view-id` has become obligatory with JSF 2.2?

`managed-bean` entries like

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>ExampleBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>my.example.package.ExampleBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

produce the similar error message:

```
A field of identity constraint 'faces-config-managed-bean-name-uniqueness' matched element 'faces-config', but this element does not have a simple type.
```

I haven't found anything about structural changes like this becoming necessary with the upgrade to JSF 2.2. *Interestingly, I didn't get this error with an intermediate change to JSF 2.1!*

Could anyone point me in a direction that might help this problem?

Comment: I already mentioned the JSF impementation and its version (MyFaces 2.2.12), but perhaps it was very clear, so I clarified the sentence a little.

Comment: Thanks, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert an empty tag `<from-view-id></from-view-id>` before `<navigation-case>`.

Example:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id></from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>go_start</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/start.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config


xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>first_page.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/first_page.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <to-view-id>/second_page.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Please add some clarification on why these changes are needed.